# Unable to cast object of type 'ComponentSpace.SAML2.Assertions.SAMLAssertion' to type 'System.Xml.XmlElement'

Tags: c#, saml-2.0

I am a Service Provider here and I use C# . My client sends the SAML response which I am trying to validate before allowing the user to access my service. For this particular client it throws unable to cast error at this line,

```
SAMLAssertion samlAssertion = new SAMLAssertion((XmlElement)(samlResponse.Assertions[0]));
```

here samlResponse is an object of SAMLResponse. Assertion is there in samlResponse but it is unable to cast that Assertion to XmlElement. 
Error,

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'ComponentSpace.SAML2.Assertions.SAMLAssertion' to type
>   'System.Xml.XmlElement'.

Here is the saml response contains signed assertion I got from my client,

```
<saml2p:Response xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Destination="My Webseite URL to receive SAML Response" ID="_3fe7259adc56de5d" IssueInstant="2018-02-20T21:00:57.313Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">IDP URL</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><ds:Reference URI="#_3fe7259adc56de5d"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs" /></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><ds:DigestValue>tuVNmHfn7RPXI1j0bzpoNuzJUXY=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>wOPI5Bjp+NUstb0udKkXslqTS4jZbvWBPj/trdTXHGq343ECWQQRFUsOfoWrFLwKvsfVqcBpMGYnICs4xS+BZU4jGktakyck0xRcRlROaIGeAZY0Ywran821h9CUdLntNqNTGrj5zyPpWGBvmvmr74oVFUo/LmPctuMWLOTfmA2n3b6VrG1YG5YEDb9VodoSWxjyKJNmZNFSriWX79U+WkTw1N3h6z4BryJwMbsMeIQN9TkwkL/qzBKSt5z1+gF54KBBm4GvJ59+Ko8mt0TflJsmSVsxq68eyqvBZp6hvDVMbNC1JRim4q+BHRU3C1OANCHM4ZUOhpKdG7Xo2VHLXw==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>Certificate </ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><saml2p:Status><saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" /></saml2p:Status><saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_3fd1bf8e757aecea" IssueInstant="2018-02-20T21:00:57.313Z" Version="2.0"><saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">IDP URL</saml2:Issuer><saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified">110015</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2018-02-20T21:03:57.313Z" Recipient="My Webseite to receive saml response" /></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject><saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2018-02-20T20:57:57.313Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-02-20T21:03:57.313Z"><saml2:AudienceRestriction><saml2:Audience>My website url to receive saml response</saml2:Audience></saml2:AudienceRestriction></saml2:Conditions><saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-02-20T20:57:57.313Z" SessionIndex="_3fd1bf8e757aecea"><saml2:SubjectLocality Address="216.6.202.133" /><saml2:AuthnContext><saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2:AuthnContext></saml2:AuthnStatement><saml2:AttributeStatement><saml2:Attribute FriendlyName="NameID" Name="NameId" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">110015</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute></saml2:AttributeStatement></saml2:Assertion></saml2p:Response>
```

PS: I tested saml response with signed assertion sample from https://www.samltool.com/generic_sso_res.php and it works fine using the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue in a codebase I've inherited and the line that throws the exception is identical to yours.

Ok, so what I've got so far is that the property Assertions holds three different things:

> The list may contain unencrypted and unsigned SAML assertions as SAMLAssertion objects, signed SAML assertions as XmlElement objects, and encrypted SAML assertions as EncryptedAssertion objects.

[Link to documentation](https://www.componentspace.com/documentation/samlv20-core/reference/api/ComponentSpace.Saml2.Protocols.SamlResponse.html#ComponentSpace_Saml2_Protocols_SamlResponse_Assertions)

I've compared our SAML responses and it seems the similarity is that our Signature elements are not children of the assertion elements.

I contacted the IdP and asked them to add a signature to the Assertion and that seems to have fixed the issue for us.

List items that are different types dependent on data, a bit smelly in my book.